# React Query mutating individual items in table by switch buttons rapidly causes buttons to turning off and on again and affecting each other

Tags: next.js, promise, react-query, uiswitch, optimistic-locking

I'm using optimistic query to update the table

```
const update = async (values: UpdateRequest) => {
  const { data } = await axios.post(
    `${update}`,
    {
      ...values,
    }
  );
  return data;
};

export const useUpdate = (): UseMutationResult<
  MutationResponse,
  Error,
  UpdateRequest,
  { previousData: Query }
> => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: (values) => updateAlert(values),
    // When mutate is called:
    onMutate: async (values: UpdateRequest) => {
      // Cancel any outgoing refetches
      // (so they don't overwrite our optimistic update)

      await queryClient.cancelQueries({
        queryKey: [queryKey],
      });

      // Snapshot the previous value
      const previousData = queryClient.getQueryData<Query>([
        queryKey,
      ]);

      // Optimistically update the data
      queryClient.setQueryData<GetAlertsResponse>(
        [queryKey],
        (oldData) => {
          const newData = oldData.item.map((item) => {
            if (item.id === values.id) {
              return {
                ...item,
                ...values,
              };
            }
            return item;
          });

          return { item: newData };
        }
      );

      // Return a context object with the snapshotted value
      return { previousData };
    },
    // If the mutation fails,
    // use the context returned from onMutate to roll back
    onError: (err, values, context) => {
      queryClient.setQueryData([queryKey], context.previousAlerts);
    },

    // Always refetch after error or success:
    onSettled: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: [queryKey] });
    },
  });
};

export default useUpdate;
```

and have a column with switch button

```
const SwitchRenderer: FC<ValueFormatterParams<AlertType>> = (params) => {
  const { value, data } = params;
  const { mutate } = useUpdate();

  const handleCheckedChange = (checked: boolean) => {
    mutate({ is_enabled: checked, id: data.id});
  };
  return (
      <SwitchComponent checked={value} onCheckedChange={handleCheckedChange} />
  );
};
```

When a rapidly change different items switch keys they are affecting their state and making them different than I desired at first. When I clicked the second one first one turning off for example. Also they are turning off and on again (flashes). Also if I clicked just one switch repeatedly and rapidly at the and it flashes also.

I tried debouncing but didn't work.
With debouncing I tried to disable the switch button until the mutation is done but didn't solve.
I also tried the solutions in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72374013/11633296 but didn't work also.

My guess is saving all the mutation requests until done then doing all off them after all settled and then invalidating queries.  For this I need to create a promise stack and listen this at the optimistic query. But I'm not sure how to do this.